# Using __new__ in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and trying my hand at classes. I do understand the difference between `__init__` and `__new__`. Here is a snippet of my class,

```
class Vector2D:

    def __new__(cls):
        print "Testing new"
        return super(Vector2D,cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return "X:" + str(self.x) + ",Y:" + str(self.y)
```

I am initializing the class like below and expecting "Testing new" to be printed first:

```
def Main():
    vec = Vector2D(1,2)
    print "Printing vec:",vec
```

but I am only getting the output,

```
Printing vec: X:1,Y:2
```

What do I have to do in the method `__new__()` for "Testing new" to be printed?

Thank you.

Comment: class Vector2D:  ===> class Vector2D(object):

Comment: @WillVousden I had to indent a couple of times here on stack to get the code style.

Comment: @Ayubx I fixed your indentation for you. Just write the code as it should be (so no extra indentation) then select the complete code block and click the `{}` button once. That will push everything over 4 spaces for the correct layout.

Comment: @KitFung Thank you. Changing `class Vector2D:` to `class Vector2D(object):` solved it but I also had change the parameters from `def __new__(cls):` to  `def __new__(cls,x,y):`

Comment: @Duncan Thank you. Will keep that in my mind for my next post.

Comment: @Duncan If i understood the last part of your answer i.e "but your superclass (object) doesn't take any parameters in its `__new__` method so don't pass them up the chain" you mean do this `def __new__(cls, *args, **kw)` instead of `def __new__(cls, x,y)` ?

Comment: @Ayubx, `def __new__(cls, x, y)` will work just as well, but if you ever added any more parameters to the `__init__` you would have to add them to `__new__` as well. The version I wrote is generic so it will ignore any parameters without further editing. Either way would be acceptable here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to make your `Vector2D` class a subclass of `object` otherwise a lot of things won't work properly. The things that won't work include `__new__` and `super`.

This should work just fine:

```
class Vector2D(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        print "Testing new"
        return super(Vector2D,cls).__new__(cls)


    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


    def __str__(self):
        return "X:" + str(self.x) + ",Y:" + str(self.y)
```

Note that the arguments used when you construct the instance are passed both to `__new__` and `__init__` so you have to be prepared to accept them in `__new__`, but your superclass (`object`) doesn't take any parameters in its `__new__` method so don't pass them up the chain.